# Uso de @Mock en Java

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Al utilizar @Mock mi @Test no funciona aunque validando a través de un simple debug funciona completamanete, no entiendo como utilizar los Mocks y lo que estoy probando es muy simple:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SepaRoutingFromXMLTest {

    @Mock
    SepaRoutingUtils sepa;

    @Test
    public void existValidOneFullXMLFileInFolder() throws Exception {
        assertThat("ARCHIVE_20141224.xml", containsString(".xml"));
        assertThat(sepa.readSepaXMLFile(), containsString("ARCHIVE_"));
    }

}
```

El primer `assertThat` funciona sin problema es muy basico, sin embargo el segundo que aparentemente es igual de trivial me devuelve:

`Expected: a string containing "SEPAROUTING_V3_FULL_" but: was null`

Como se puede ver estoy haciendo un mock de:

```
@Component
public class SepaRoutingUtils {

    public String readSepaXMLFile() {
        return "ARCHIVE_20141224.xml";
    }

}
```

Que para mi es basicamente lo mismo, pero me doy cuenta de que no entiendo el funcionamiento de @Mock y tampoco puedo hacer un @Autowired de esa clase porque pienso que no se debe hacer en el @Test.

Veo que al hacer la siguiente modificacion funciona correctamente:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SepaRoutingFromXMLTest {

    @Test
    public void existValidOneFullXMLFileInFolder() throws Exception {
        SepaRoutingUtils sepa = new SepaRoutingUtils(); 
        assertThat(sepa.readSepaXMLFile(), containsString(".xml"));
        assertThat(sepa.readSepaXMLFile(), containsString("ARCHIVE_"));
    }

}
```

Sin embargo hacer esto no me sirve porque en la classe `SepaRoutingUtils` debo obtener un valor con @Value:

```
@Value("${from.folder}")
private String FROM_FOLDER;
```

Sé que puedo estar errado e varios conceptos.

Actualizacion de la clase `SepaRoutingUtils`

```
@Component
public class SepaRoutingUtils {

    @Value("${from.folder}")
    private String FROM_FOLDER;

    private File readSepaFolder() {

        File folder = new File(FROM_FOLDER);
        if(!folder.isDirectory()) {
            throw new FolderAccessDeniedException();
        }

        return folder;
    }

    public String readSepaXMLFile(SepaRoutingFileType fileType) {

        try {
            return Utils.prepareXMLFile(readSepaFolder(), fileType).getName();
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new NotValidFileException();      
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complementando la respuesta correcta en terminos generales de @SJuan76.

Para tu caso en particular quieres realizar un mock de un miembro privado al cual no le puedes hacer `@Mock/@Spy` por ser una clase final (String)

Una posible solucion podria ser utilizar *reflection* para agregarle un valor comprobable a ese String:

```
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SepaRoutingUtilsTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SepaRoutingUtils sepa;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws NoSuchFieldException {
        Field field = SepaRoutingUtils.class.getDeclaredField("FROM_FOLDER");
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        ReflectionUtils.setField(field, sepa, "ARCHIVE_20141224.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void existValidOneFullXMLFileInFolder() throws Exception {
        assertThat("ARCHIVE_20141224.xml", containsString(".xml"));
        assertThat(sepa.readSepaXMLFile(), containsString("ARCHIVE_"));
    }

}
```

Comment: No, no me funciona es decir cambié @ Autowired por @InjectMocks pero aun asi debo mantener la propiedad como una propiedad de la clase y no puedo pasarla desde @ Value. Es extraño porque tengo otras clases en el mismo paquete y la clase principal anotada con @ SpringBootApplication y en el paquete base de la applicacion.

Comment: Pero no te he dicho que elimines la propiedad, solo te mostre como pasarle un valor en el momento de realizar el test

Comment: Ahora si entendi lo que me dices y se ve muy poderoso, sin embargo el valor sigue perdiendose por ejemplo si hago `File folder = new File(FROM_FOLDER);` me da un NullPointerException.

Comment: Tendría que ver el código que estas testiando para entenderlo. En que comento haces el new?

Comment: He actualizado la clase al hacer `File folder = new File(FROM_FOLDER);` y ejecutar el test me da un NullPointerException.

Comment: no veo como puede darte un `NullPointerException` en ese contexto. Deberias obtener un objeto `File`, los problemas los deberias tener en lograr cubrir el resto del codigo, que sea un directory o que el `Utils.prepareXMLFile()` pueda ejecutarse correctamente

Answer (score 1):

Haces `mocks` para reemplazar componentes de los que depende el código que pruebas. Así puedes probar un componente sin depender de si los componentes reemplazados funcionan correctamente o no.

Tu componente hace tal que así<sup>1</sup>:

```
public MiComponente {
   @Autowired MiComponentePersistencia persistencia;

   public int getSuma(String param) {
      int[] datos = persistencia.getNumeros(param);
      int resultado = 0;
      for (int dato : datos) {
         resultado += dato;
      }
      return resultado;
   }
}
```

¿Cómo pruebas `getSuma()`? El valor que obtienes dependerá de lo que `persistencia.getNumeros()` te devuelve, así que si no controlas eso no podrás hacer el test (o al menos, no podrás validar el resultado).

Así que

```
@Mock
MiComponentePersistencia persistencia;

@InjectMocks
MiComponente compAProbar;

@Test
public void testSuma() {
   when (persistencia.getNumeros("hola")).thenReturn(new int[]{1, 2});
   assertEquals("Valor de la suma", 3, compAProbar.getSuma("hola"));
}
```

Y sí, podrías simplemente hacer tu implementación "a mano" de `MiComponentePersistencia` para hacer lo mismo. Los frameworks de `mock` simplemente te facilitan la tarea mucho.

---

<sup>1</sup>Realmente tengo más experiencia con Java EE y Mockito que con Spring, así que me disculparás si algo de Spring no es totalmente correcto.