# Java Modificar una propiedad para realizar un @Test

Tags: java, spring

Realizando algunos Test en Java me encuentro con dos problemas al probar la funcion para obtener un archivo desde una carpeta que esta en las propiedades de la applicacion:

El primer problema es que al hacer el `@Test` no me reconoce el valor extraido desde `${routing.folder}`, cosa que no me ocurre ejecutando y haciendo debug al codigo, por eso la he dejado comentada y copiado directamente su valor. A continuacion comparto el Test y la Clase:

SepaRoutingFromXMLTest.java :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SepaRoutingUtils.class})
public class SepaRoutingFromXMLTest {

    @Autowired
    SepaRoutingUtils sepa;

    @Test
    public void existValidOneFullXMLFileInFolder() throws Exception {
        SepaRoutingUtils sepa = new SepaRoutingUtils(); 
        assertThat(sepa.readSepaXMLFile(), containsString(".xml"));
        assertThat(sepa.readSepaXMLFile(), containsString("SEPAROUTING_V3_FULL_"));
    }

}
```

SepaRoutingUtils.java :

```
@Component
public class SepaRoutingUtils {

    // @Value("${routing.folder}")
    // private String SEPA_FOLDER
    private final String SEPA_FOLDER = "../../separouting";

    private File readSepaFolder() {

        File folder = new File(SEPA_FOLDER);
        if(!folder.isDirectory()) {
            throw new FolderAccessDeniedException();
        }

        return folder;
    }

    public String readSepaXMLFile() {

        try {
            return Utils.prepareXMLFile(readSepaFolder(), SepaRoutingFileType.FULL).getName();
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new NotValidFileException();      
        }

    }

}
```

La funcion `Utils.prepareXMLFile` me devuelve el archivo que necesito para luego procesarlo, valida entre otras cosas el nombre del archivo y solo toma el mas actualizado.

El segundo inconveniente es que si quisiera algo como `@Test(expected = FolderAccessDeniedException.class)` no lo podia probar porque se supone que el valor se toma de las propiedades y sencillamente este valor no se puede modificar desde el `@Test`. Y siempre resultaria correcto ó incorrecto.

Entonces no sé como hacer que falle cuando por ejemplo una ruta no exista o no sea accesible. He pensado en cambiar la funcion para que la ruta de la carpeta se le pase a la funcion `readSepaFolder()` sin embargo no me gustaria dejarlo asi.

Comment: Con respecto a tu `@Value` no te sirvió la respuesta que te di en tu otra pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/148442/73136

Comment: No, no me funciona es decir cambié @ Autowired por @InjectMocks pero aun asi debo mantener la propiedad como una propiedad de la clase y no puedo pasarla desde @ Value.

Answer (score 0):

La clase `SepaRoutingUtils` que estás pasando como parámetro en `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SepaRoutingUtils.class})` no es una clase de configuración. Es un Bean.

Si quieres un contexto diferente para tests, deberías pasar como parámetro la clase que contiene la configuración (normalmente anotada `@Configuration`). Si quieres usar el mismo contexto en los tests que en la ejecución normal de la aplicación puedes usar la anotación `@ContextConfiguration` sin parámetros.